# Send keystroke to non-foreground window

Tags: c#, .net, keypress, simulate

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx) on msdn, it is possible to set a specific window as the foreground window, and *then* send keystrokes to it... but I need to send keystrokes to a window in the background, so that whatever the user is doing can continue uninterrupted.

Comment: This is not possible in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just catch the keystrokes in your foreground window and pass them to the background window (delegate). Or if they are somewhat complex you could use global hotkeys. Anyways passing the keys from your foreground form to your background form should be the better solution.

I found a nice example it's not about hotkeys but the concept should apply in your case as well.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/pass_data_between_forms.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So basically a keystroke listener? Java has a robot class that listens for keystrokes and can act upon them (ex. me typing "Hello World" and the class will automatically write that to a file or other window).

I've created something similar in the past. You can create a java program to run in the background in a constant while loop and just listen for keystrokes. Set the program to write each keystroke to a file or specific place. Because this is a short while loop and only reacts when a key is pressed, it takes up almost no processing power and does not affect the performance of the program in the foreground.

Comment: I need the program in the background to receive keyevents as if it was focused and the user pressed a key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with shortcut keys.  I have an application that has multiple child windows along the side.  The main window enables the [Form.KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property of the child windows and then registers for the appropriate event (KeyPress, KeyDown or KeyUp) on that child window.  With this setup the main window can process all the keys from the child windows.

Answer (score 0):

The technique I've used on Windows Mobile/CE is to hook the keyboard and then simply use  `PostMessage()` to send them to the target window to be handled as normal.  This technique should also work on the desktop. There are several examples on Code Project of hooking the keyboard - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx.  Your question was not clear if the foreground window was part of your application or not.  If it is, wouldn't you simply subscribe to one of foreground form key events from the background form?